# Cannot access object property using variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var set_1 = {
    id: 'set_1',
    nameofSet : 'English fruits',
    category: 'languages',
    cards : [
        {
            front : 'apple',
            back : 'jablko'
        },
        {
            front : 'orange',
            back : 'pomarancza'
        },
        {
            front : 'pear',
            back : 'gruszka'
        }
    ]
}
```

Now there's a function:

```
$('#chooseSet').on('click', '.setName', function() {
    var setName = this.getAttribute("data-set-name");
    editCards(setName);
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="setName" data-set-name="set_1">English fruits</div>
```

It gives the `setName` parameter to the `editCards` function that looks like this:

```
editCards(setName) {
    console.log(setName); // logs "set_1"
    console.log(setName.cards); // logs "undefined" - why?
    console.log(set_1.cards);  // logs the `cards` array from `set_1'.
    // code
}
```

It takes the `setName` parameter.

My question is - why doesn't the second `console.log` give me the `cards' array as it does in the third`console.log` example?

Comment: `console.log(window[setName].cards)`

Answer (score 4):

Because any attribute's value is a string. So in your case `data-set-name` returns the string `"set_1"`, which is not a reference to the variable `set_1`. If your `set_1` variable is global, you should be able to do this instead -

`console.log(window[setName].cards)`

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I will accept your answer in a few minutes when it's possible.